# RxJava: How to repeat an observable chain when original condition is not met anymore?

Tags: java, rx-java

I'd like to re-subscribe to an observable using `repeat()`, but the condition that triggers the original observable is not met anymore when the first subscription is finished. How would I re-subscribe the observer in this case?

The code looks something like this:

```
RxInput.onInput(grid)
    .flatMap(Grid::handle)
    .flatMap(Grid::check)
    .delay(300, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
    .flatMap(Grid::clean)
    .repeat() // Does not work
    .subscribe(g -> {System.out.println("Finished");});
```

The code of `RxInput.onInput()` is like this:

```
public static <T> Observable<T> onInput(T t) {
    return Observable.create(subscriber -> {
        if(InputSystem.isInputOn()) { // This is not true anymore when re-subscribing
            subscriber.onNext(t);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: One thing you can do is create an actual `OnSubscribe` class and keep a member stating if this was started or not.

Comment: As far as I understand [the documentation](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/repeat.html) repeat does not resubscribe to anything. It just collects emitted items and re-emits them. So it's hard to tell what you are trying to achieve and why it doesn't work for you.

Comment: `repeat` does resubscribe (you can see it in the source)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that you seem to want to prevent emissions from initial subscription  if `isInputOn` is false then define the observable like this:

```
Observable.defer(
  () -> {
     if (!InputSystem.isInputOn())
       return Observable.empty();
     else 
       return yourInput
         .flatMap(Grid::handle)
         .flatMap(Grid::check)
         .delay(300, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
         .flatMap(Grid::clean)
         .repeat();
    })
  .subscribe(...);
```

A quick extra note, do your damndest to avoid using `Observable.create` like in your example above. If you do emit things like that then you need to combine your observable with `.onBackpressureXXX()` because you may get a `MissingBackpressureException` from operators like `flatMap` downstream.